# What settings are required to put AWS CloudFront CDN in front of a squarespace website?

Tags: cdn, amazon-cloudfront, squarespace

I had trouble getting AWS CloudFront to work with SquareSpace. Issues with forms not submitting and the site saying website expired. What are the settings that are needed to get CloudFront working with a Squarespace site?

Comment: It seems like SquareSpace has a CDN already (at least for images/assets). Why are you wanting to put another one in front of it?

Comment: Mainly to use the SSL from AWS and redirect paths to different orgins e.g. https://example.com/ > squarespace
https://example.com/othersystem > something hosted elsewhere

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is definitely doable, considering I just set this up. Let me share the settings I used on Cloudfront, Squarespace, and Route53 to make it work. If you want to use a different DNS provide than AWS Route53, you should be able to adapt these settings. Keep in mind that this is not an e-commerce site, but a standard site with a **blog**, **static pages**, and **forms**. You can likely adapt these instructions for other issues as/if they come up.

## Cloudfront (CDN)

---

To make this work, you need to create a **Cloudfront Distribution** for **Web**.

#### Origin Settings

- **Origin Domain Name** should be set to **ext-cust.squarespace.com**. This is Squarespace's entry point for external domain names.
- **Origin Path** can be left blank.
- **Origin ID** is just the unique ID for this distribution and should auto-populate if you're on the distribution creation screen, or be fixed if you're editing Origin Settings later.
- **Origin Custom Headers** do not need to be set.

#### Default Cache Behavior Settings / Behaviors

- **Path Patterns** should be left at **Default**.
- I have **Viewer Protocol Policy** set to **Redirect HTTP to HTTPS**. This dictates whether your site can use one or both of HTTP or HTTPS. I prefer to have all traffic routed securely, so I redirect all HTTP traffic to HTTPS. Note that you cannot do the reverse and redirect HTTPS to HTTP, as this will cause authentication issues (your browser doesn't want to expose what you *thought* was a secure connection).
- **Allowed HTTP Methods** needs to be **GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, PUT, POST, PATCH, DELETE**. This is because forms (and other things such as comments, probably) use the **POST** HTTP method to work.
- **Cached HTTP Methods** I left to just **GET, HEAD**. No need for anything else here.
- **Forward Headers** needs to be set to **All** or **Whitelist**. Squarespace's entry point we mentioned earlier needs to know where what domain you're coming from to serve your site, so the **Host** header must be whitelisted, or allowed with everything else if set to All.
- **Object Caching**, **Minimum TTL**, **Maximum TTL**, and **Default TTL** can all be left at their defaults.
- **Forward Cookies** cookies is the missing component to get forms working. Either you can set this to **All**, or **Whitelist**. There are certain session variables that Squarespace uses for validation, security, and other utilities. I have added the following values to **Whitelist Cookies**: `JSESSIONID, SS_MID, crumb, ss_cid, ss_cpvisit, ss_cvisit, test`. Make sure to put each value on a separate line, without commas.
- **Forward Query Strings** is set to **True**, as some Squarespace API calls use query strings so these must be passed along.
- **Smooth Streaming**, **Restrict Viewer Access**, and **Compress Objects Automatically** can all be left at their default values, or chosen as required if you know you need them to be set differently.

#### Distribution Settings / General

- **Price Class** and **AWS WAF Web ACL** can be left alone.
- **Alternate Domain Names** should list your domain, and your domain with the www subdomain attached, e.g. `example.com, www.example.com`.
- For *SSL Certificate*, please follow the tutorial [here](https://bryce.fisher-fleig.org/blog/setting-up-ssl-on-aws-cloudfront-and-s3/) to upload your certificate to IAM if you haven't already, then refresh your certificates (there is a control next to the dropdown for this), select **Custom SSL Certificate** and select the one you've provisioned. This ensures that browsers recognize your SSL over HTTPS as valid. This is not necessary if you're not using HTTPS at all.
- All following settings can be left at default, or chosen to meet your own specific requirements.

## Route 53 (DNS)

---

- You need to have a **Hosted Zone** set up for your domain (this is specific to Route 53 setup).
- You need to set an **A** record to point to your Cloudfront distribution.
- You should set a **CNAME** record for the **www** subdomain name pointing to your Cloudfront distribution, even if you don't plan on using it (later we'll go through setting Squarespace to only use the root domain by redirecting the www subdomain)

## Squarespace

---

On your Squarespace site, you simply need to go to `Settings->Domains->Connect a Third-Party Domain`. Once there, enter your domain and continue. Under the domain's settings, you can uncheck **Use WWW Prefix** if you'd like people accessing your site from `www.example.com` to redirect to the root, `example.com`. I prefer this, but it's up to you. Under **DNS Settings**, the only value you need is CNAME that points to **verify.squarespace.com**. Add this CNAME record to your DNS settings on Route 53, or other DNS provider. It won't ever say that your connection has been fully completed since we're using a custom way of deploying, but that won't matter.

Your site should now be operating through Cloudfront pointing to your Squarespace deployment! Please note that DNS propogation takes time, so if you're unable to access the site, give it some time (up to several hours) to propogate.

## Notes

---

I can't say exactly whether each and every one of the values set under **Whitelist Cookies** is necessary, but these are taken from using the Chrome Inspector to determine what cookies were present under the **Cookie** header in the request. Initially I tried to tell Cloudfront to whitelist the Cookie header itself, but it does not allow that (presumably because it wants you to use the cookie-specific whitelist). If your deployment is not working, see if there are more cookies being transmitted in your requests (under the Cookie header, the values you're looking for should look like `my_cookie=somevalue;other_cookie=othervalue`—`my_cookie` and `other_cookie` in my example are what you'd add to the whitelist).

The same procedure can be used to forward other headers entirely that may be needed via the **Forward Headers** whitelist. Simply inspect and see if there's something that looks like it might need to go through.

Remember, if you're not whitelisting a header or cookie, it's not getting to Squarespace. If you don't want to bother, or everything is effed (pardon my language), you can always set to allow all headers/cookies, although this *adversely affects caching performance*.  So be conservative if you can.

Hope this helps!

Comment: sometimes I got 504 error from CloudFront, do you have a clue?

Comment: @syg I see frequent 504 errors on our website as well. Have you found a fix?

Comment: Trying these settings today, but form submissions (like a contact form) fail with 401 errors, even with passing all headers and cookies through. Are form submissions working for you?

Comment: @JeffSheets a little late, sorry, but yes, at the time form submissions were working. I would attempt a cache invalidation and see if that works. 401 is, of course, forbidden, which is at least a clue. If you did figure this out, I'd be curious as to what the issues was, otherwise, I'd need to know more about your setup to really have a clue. One are I'd definitely check, though, is in your **Whitelist Cookie** and **Forward Headers** settings. Those can definitely trip you up.

Comment: @Psiloc we were never able to figure it out, so i'm not sure. The goal for us was to host iOS/android deep link files. We ended up using a workardound to host squarespace from www, and our aws layer from non-www and redirects to the www site. So example.com hits AWS, and www.example.com hits Squarespace.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the settings to get CloudFront working with Squarespace!

## Behaviours:

- **Allowed HTTP Methods** Ensure that you select: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, PUT, POST, PATCH, DELETE. Otherwise forms will not work:
- **Forward Headers:** Select whitelist and choose 'Host'. Otherwise squarespace will not know which website they need to load up and you get the message 'Website has expired' or similar.

## Origins:

- **Origin Domain Name** set as: ext-cust.squarespace.com
- **Origin Protocol Policy** Select HTTPS so that traffic between the CDN and the origin is secure too

## General

- **Alternate Domain Names (CNAMEs)** put both your www and none www addresses here and let Squarespace decide on if to direct www to root or vice-versa (.e.g example.com www.example.com)
  You can now configure SSL on CloudFront
- **HTTPS** You can now enforce HTTPS using a certificate for your site here rather than in Squarespace

---

### Setting I'm unsure about still:

- **Forward Query Strings**: recommended not for caching reasons but I think this could break things...

---

## Route53

Create A records for www and root (e.g. example.com www.example.com) and set as an alias to your CloudFront distribution

Comment: You need to forward query strings if either (a) your application actually uses them or (b) if you want to be able to use then for cache-busting at CloudFront and the browser.  If you don't forward them, CloudFront pretends as though they never arrived, so you can only use them for browser-side cache-busting only.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than whitelist any headers, cookies or query strings, which may affect the cache key, it's better to set up an Origin Request Policy to send all headers, query strings and cookies.  You'll need to create the policy yourself - for headers it's "All viewer headers", for Query Strings it's "All" and for cookies it's "All" too.